# Universal Windows App Webview memory leak - clear cache

Tags: c#, caching, memory-leaks, webview, win-universal-app

I am developing a UWP-App which has a webview control on it.
Most of our code is JavaScript. 
The app consumes tons of ram over the time and we have no clue where this memory leak comes from. The is almost no nativ code running, most of it is javascript, we cleared the DOM which is only about 5MB. The size of the app at this moment is about 300MB. I also tried to run the GC with almost no effect. 
At start the app has a size of about 50MB, Increasing fast to about 100mb and then slowly consumes more and more RAM. I had a maximum of 1.8GB.
Does anyone has/had the same problem? Is it a equivalent leak than the webbrowser control had?

**Update**

The cause of the Problem is the growing cache of the WebView. Is there any chance to clear the cache, without closing the app?

Comment: Could the javascript account for the amount of memory being used?  Does the amount memory used stabilize or does it keep growing?

Comment: it keeps groing as long the app is running. And we don't have this effect on android and ios..

Comment: were you able to find a way to clear webview's cache ?

Comment: no, but I know the problem is that the heap isn't cleared. I just don't know where all the data comes from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seams, the problem wasn't the cache, but the Intel App Framework we use.
The Framework we use is an elder version (2.0) which doesn't release the references properly. 
An update to version 3.0 solved the problem.